# Stub function does not executed when executing test using sinon and mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, sinon

I'm trying to mock a function in order to pass tests using `sinon` and `mocha`.

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const { isValid } = require('./utils/index');

const config = require('./config.json')[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development']


const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res)=> {


    const url = config.url;
   try {
    const validUrl = isValid(url)
    .then(() => {
        return res.redirect(`https://${url}`);
    })
    .catch(() => {
        return res.status(400).send('Unable to redirect to the given url');
    })
   } catch(error) {
      return res.send('Internal Server Error') 
   }




})

const port = process.env.port || 3000;

const server = app.listen(port, ()=> {
    console.log('server listens on 127.0.0.1:3000');
})

module.exports = {server, app};
```

config.json:

```
{
"development": {
    "url": "www.stackoverflow.com"
}, 
"test": {
    "url": "www.stackoverflow.com"
}

}
```

utils/index.js:

```
const http = require('http');


module.exports.isValid = (url) => {
    const options = {
        method: 'HEAD',
        host: url
    }
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = http.request(options, () => {
        return resolve(true)
    })
    req.on('error', () => {
        return reject(new Error('Not valid'))
    })

    req.end();
})

return promise;
}
```

test/index.js:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const index = require('../utils/index')
const { expect } = chai;

const { server } = require('../app');
const {url} = require('../config.json')['test'];



describe('isValid Test', () => {

    it('Should redirects an error when the url is not valid', async() => {

        const stub = sinon.stub(index, 'isValid');
        stub.withArgs(url).returns(Promise.reject(new Error('Not Valid')));
        const { status } = await request(server).get('/');

        expect(status).to.equal(400);

    })
})
```

When I execute the test I got this error:

```
    (node:23622) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Not Valid
    at Context.it (/home/hs/perso/mockTests/chaiMock/test/index.js:17:52)
    at callFn (/home/hs/perso/mockTests/chaiMock/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:387:21)
    at Test.Runnable.run (/home/hs/perso/mockTests/chaiMock/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:379:7)
    at Runner.runTest (/home/hs/perso/mockTests/chaiMock/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:535:10)
    at /home/hs/perso/mockTests/chaiMock/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:653:12
    at next (/home/hs/perso/mockTests/chaiMock/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:447:14)
    at /home/hs/perso/mockTests/chaiMock/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:457:7
    at next (/home/hs/perso/mockTests/chaiMock/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:362:14)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/home/hs/perso/mockTests/chaiMock/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:425:5)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
(node:23622) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:23622) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
url:  www.stackoverflow.com
    1) Should redirects an error when the url is not valid


  0 passing (122ms)
  1 failing

  1) isValid Test
       Should redirects an error when the url is not valid:

      AssertionError: expected 302 to equal 400
      + expected - actual

      -302
      +400

      at Context.it (test/index.js:22:27)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your app module is required and in turn pulls in the utils/index file before sinon stubs the function you're interested in, I believe the module loader then caches it so sinon trying to stub it has no effect.

To see your test pass successfully, you need to stub your isValid function before you require your app i.e.

```
const request = require('supertest');
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { expect } = chai;

const index = require('../utils/index');

/* Stub here before the server is required */
const stub = sinon.stub(index, 'isValid');

const { server } = require('../app');
const { url } = require('../config.json')['test'];

describe('isValid Test', () => {
  it('Should redirects an error when the url is not valid', async () => {
    stub.withArgs(url).rejects('Not Valid');

    const { status } = await request(server).get('/');

    expect(status).to.equal(400);
  });
});
```

Also, to stop seeing the unhandled promise rejection when your tests run, you can use the [`.rejects()` function](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/#stubrejectsvalue) rather than creating your own rejected promise.

Answer (score -1):

Try to check the value you are send at "host" on your request, I believe you are hitting at "www.stackoverflow.com" and getting a http code 400 that's why you are getting an error on your test

Comment: Normally, if the url is valid (in my case `www.stackoverflow.com`) the api redirect to the page of stackoverflow.Otherwise, it return an error.In my test, I want to mock the result returned by `isValid` according to given url.

Comment: Yea, but are you *sure* the url paremeter you are receiving in the isValid(url) isn't www.stackoverflow.com ?
Because you can't receive an httpCode of 400 if you are sending a invalid url

Comment: the url was `www.stackoverflow.com`, in `process.env.development = developement` the api will redirect to the stackoverflow page. Unless when `process.env.NODE_ENV= test` the stub should mock the response of `isValid`. In my test I want to return an error then the status code should be 400. In my case the stub is not called.It's executed but is not called when `request(app).get('/')` was called.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but in the config.json file you have the same URL configured for both development, and test